# Typeahead.js remote call restriction

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I am using Twitter's Typeahead.js with around 15 remote calls. In the example below,  part of my code is given with the names "list1" and "list2". My actual codes goes till list15 from list1.

```
                  {
                    name: "list1",
                    remote: "/get-list1/%QUERY",
                    template: "<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> - {{extract}}</p>",
                    engine: Hogan,
                    maxParallelRequests : 15                         
                  },
                  {
                    name: "list2",
                    remote: "/get-list2/%QUERY",
                    template: "<p><strong>{{value}}</strong></p>",
                    engine: Hogan,
                    maxParallelRequests : 15                         
                  },
```

The code works without any issues. But only remote calls are made only for the first 6 datums and the rest are ignored. When I did some reading, I came to know that there is a default limit of maximum number of remote calls (maxParallelRequests).

```
maxParallelRequests – The max number of parallel requests typeahead.js can 
                      have pending. Defaults to 6.
```

As seen in the above code, I have set the maxParallelRequests value to 15, but still it executes only 6 remote calls.

Is my method of providing the setting wrong? Please correct me what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to be specifying maxParallelRequests in a remote object, at least according to the docs.

```
{
                name: "list1",
                remote: {
                   url: "/get-list1/%QUERY",
                   maxParallelRequests: 15
                },
                template: "<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> - {{extract}}</p>",
                engine: Hogan
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do we need to provide this for all the datum or just for 1 is enough?

Comment: Adding this to all datum remote call does not make sense to me.. or its must to provide this to all 15 datum?

Comment: FYI - I added the maxParallelRequests only to the first datum and it worked well. I am able to execute multiple remote calls. Thanks.

Comment: It does seem a bit strange that the option would be set on each remote object (or at least one). I haven't dived into the source to see why.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but how about using Bloodhound, where should I add this maxParallelRequests?

Answer (score 1):

**typeahead.bundle.js** file in setting

```
maxPendingRequests = 6
```

change:

```
maxPendingRequests = 16
```

Comment: in the minified this would be changing the g in `g=6,h=new e(10);return c.setMaxPendingRequests=function(a){g=a}` to `g=16`